# LXDE startup, multi-terminal programmes

Tags: lxde

My LXDE startup at  /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
has this in it '@termit -e ncmpcpp' which starts ncmpcpp, a MPD
backend. Termit is a rather nice terminal with tabs that auto-resizes
to the name you enter into it. But I use many tabs in it, currently
eight of various programmes.But, how do I get all of them to open up
in one tabbed-interface terminal of 'termit' please?

If I did '@termit -e ncmpcpp' I cant then add onto it '@termit -e
nload/glances/weather/wyrd' as it just fails. Has anyone else come
across this sort of problem before please?

Thanks
Sharon.